# Generating test data - how to generate a valid address for a given US zipcode?

Tags: python, street-address, data-generation

I am creating a tool which depends on addresses. For the purposes of testing, I'd like to create a large number of valid US addresses. I have the [GeoNames postal code data](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) and I would like to generate some number of real addresses for each of the ~41,000 zip codes in the United States.

I've found sites like [FakeAddressGenerator](https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/US_Real_Random_Address) and [FakeName](https://fakena.me/random-real-address/) which claim to generate random, valid US addresses. How do these sites work? How can I do the same thing without relying on scraping these websites?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this in Python; utilizing a web service is fine (it doesn't seem that either FakeAddressGenerator or FakeName provide such a web service).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Seems like "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" to me.

Comment: You should use faker library

Comment: @BurakÖztürk the problem about faker library is that it does not guarantee that the addresses will be real.

Comment: What is the need for a valid address in testing? Can't you mock data or responses?

Comment: I am indeed looking to create mock data, but I wish that the addresses in my mock data are valid because I am hoping to allow myself and users of this mock data (e.g, those who are learning web development) to be able to integrate/mashup the mock data with Google Maps and have it actually show up properly.

Comment: There are online sites and services that have addressed (pun intended) this problem such as http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Googling your issue I found 2 links of interest:

1. https://github.com/EthanRBrown/rrad that provides approximately 3200 real anonymised addresses.
2. https://openaddresses.io that also has a link to their open source github with the complete data set.

I don't recommend scraping the fake address generators as they do not guarantee existence. I would not go sampling in google maps either as you will surely get blacklisted.

Extracting data from downloaded zip file in 2 is easy: they are zip files containing csv files with full address, zip, lat, lon, etc...

The two above data sets "guarantee" the existence of the address. I don't know how hard your other conditions are, namely having at least one valid address for *each* of the 41k zip codes. If this is a hard constraint, I doubt you will get such data set open source.

---

**EDIT:**

If you have a list of all postcodes in the US, a fully automatable solution is by using a service called nominatim of openstreetmap(subject to their TOCs!)

1) get the lat, lon (centre point or default address) of each post code:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/?format=xml&addressdetails=1&limit=1&country_codes=us&postalcode=35051

2) get the related address of this lat, lon:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=33.178764&lon=-86.619038&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

trying this example for Columbiana in Alabama (postcode 35051) yields 397 West College Street.

Nominatim documentation is at: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Comment: I won't have a chance to try this out for a couple days, but it looks like you've found the perfect solution to my problem with nominatim! I will follow up and award the bounty in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

You can install random-address:

```
pip install random-address
```

And then use random_address.real_random_address_by_postal_code:

```
>>> import random_address
>>> random_address.real_random_address_by_postal_code('32409')
{'address1': '711 Tashanna Lane', 'address2': '', 'city': 'Southport', 'state': 'FL', 'postalCode': '32409', 'coordinates': {'lat': 30.41437699999999, 'lng': -85.676568}}
```

Comment: Heads up - this does not work for most states/zip codes. The PyPi page lists the set of states and locations this works for - https://pypi.org/project/random-address/